# Using php 5.0 to upload xml into Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a xml as follows-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
<item>
    <mid>2557</mid>
    <merchantname>DVD Players</merchantname>
    <linkid>1000012</linkid>
    <createdon>2006-09-30/20:04:17</createdon>
    <sku> JR-E-12324</sku>
    <productname>Sony Blu-Ray DVD Player</productname>
    <category>
        <primary>Electronics</primary>
        <secondary>TV . Video</secondary>
    </category>
    <price currency="JPY">59704</price>
    <upccode>4901340995017</upccode>
    <description>
        <short>Awesome Pictures</short>
        <long>Watch all your HD-DVDs</long>
    </description>
    <keywords>DVD Player~~BluRay~~SONY</keywords>
    <linkurl>http://somelink.com</linkurl>
    <imageurl>image.gif</imgurl>
</item>
```

I need to upload above xml to mysql table sing php. can someone help ?thanks

Comment: so write the query, and run it.

Comment: Do you want to save the string?  Do you need to save all the elements to a separate column?  What are the requirements here?

Comment: Yes, i want to save all the elements in separate columns in a single table.

Comment: @sanjay and why is your doubt?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Is there something you are having trouble with?

Comment: @sanjay - If you show what you have tried, then more people will help you

Comment: I did something like this-                                       $oDOM = new DOMDocument();
$oDOM->loadXML(file_get_contents('myfile.xml'));
foreach ($oDOM->getElementsByTagName('result') as $results1)
{

$Subject=mysql_real_escape_string($results1->getElementsByTagName('mid')->item(0)->nodeValue);
$Event=mysql_real_escape_string($results11->getElementsByTagName('merchantname')->item(0).VALUE);

}

$sql = "insert into `mytable` ..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try SimpleXML's Load String Method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)